# PowerShell AD Script using Get-ADGroup - Invalid Enumeration Context

Tags: powershell, active-directory, directorysearcher

I am using this script to extract a load of information to a tab delimited flat text file that is used by another program. The script works well, creating the file and populating it with data, but when it reaches around 250MB of data, I get the error listed below. I believe that this is being caused as I'm just trying to gather too much data, but I'm not sure how to fix it!

Script:

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
    $Domain = 'DomainName'
    Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * | ForEach-Object {
        $Group = $_
        Get-ADGroup $Group -Properties Members | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members | Get-ADObject | ?{$_.ObjectClass -eq "user"} |  
            Get-ADUser -Properties * | Select-Object @{
              Name = 'Domain'
                Expression = { $Domain }
          }, @{
              Name = 'Group Name'
                Expression = { $Group.Name }
          }, @{
              Name = 'Type'
                Expression = { $Group.GroupCategory }
          }, @{
              Name = 'Description'
              Expression = { $_.Description }
          }, @{
                Name = 'Distinguished Name'
              Expression = { $_.DistinguishedName }
            }, @{
                Name = 'Managed By'
                Expression = { $Group.ManagedBy }
            }, @{
                Name = 'Members'
              Expression = { $_.MemberOf }
            }, @{
                Name = 'Full Name'
              Expression = { $_.Name }
            }, @{
              Name = 'User Name'
              Expression = { $_.SamAccountName }
          }, @{
              Name = 'Display Name'
              Expression = { $_.DisplayName }
          }
    } | Export-Csv -delimiter "`t" -path C:\Test.txt –nti
```

[image: Error:]

Edit: I have tried to use the directorysearcher tool as I know that gets round the indexing issue, however I can't get the code right. I need to get users and group information. I've got the user information but its not picking up data for all users, how can I search for all users in a domain?

```
    Import-module ACtiveDirectory
    $Domain = 'domain'

    $strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
    $objCollection=@()
    $objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

    $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
    $objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
    $objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
    $objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

    $colProplist = "name", "samaccountname", "description", "distinguishedname", "memberof", "displayname"
    foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

    $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

    $objCollection = $colResults | select -Expand Properties |
    select @{
        n = 'Domain'
            e = { $Domain }
    }, @{
        n = 'Group Name'
            e = { $Group.Name }
    }, @{
        n = 'Type'
            e = { $Group.GroupCategory }
    }, @{
        n = 'Description'
        e = { $_.description }
    }, @{
            n = 'Distinguished Name'
        e = { $_.distinguishedname }
        }, @{
            n = 'Managed By'
            e = { $Group.ManagedBy }
        }, @{
            n = 'Members'
        e = { $_.memberof }
        }, @{
            n = 'Full Name'
        e = { $_.name }
        }, @{
        n = 'User Name'
        e = { $_.samaccountname }
    }, @{
        n = 'Display Name'
        e = { $_.displayname }
    }

    $objCollection | Export-Csv -delimiter "`t" -path C:\Test9.txt -nti
```

Comment: A few hints here, maybe? http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2007/07/24/optimize-powershell-performance-and-memory-consumption/

Comment: What happens if you run `Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties *` by itself?

Comment: Well the script runs for about an hour logging 250MB of data, so it must be working to start with. I think im filling the memory or something. Will try running just that command

Comment: I think the problem is probably occurring in the long pipeline you are doing inside the foreach loop, but just wanted to make sure that the initial command worked correctly. You could probably improve everything by A: removing -properties * from your get's since you are only wanting specific info and B: utilizing get-adgroupmember to get rid of most of that pipeline

Comment: @NoahSparks Thanks, I did initially have Get-ADGroupMember, but removed it to do this work around as there was a limit on the number of members it could return and this was was a work around. 
I will remove the properties * variable and try that, as you're right I do not need that. This following link explains what I am experiencing, however I do not have permissions to change the AD so I need a script based work around instead of indexing the AD. http://jeffwouters.nl/index.php/2013/09/1760/

Comment: You're welcome. Interesting. I'll be curious to see if removing properties * helps...if it's the same problem he was experiencing (non-indexed property) it sounds like it might.

Comment: @NoahSparks It came back with the same error at the same point, trying now to remove properties * in the AD User command, even though the error isnt referenced at that line. I have also found online that this is a common issue due to indexing of a parameter and unless the parameter is indexed on the AD then the only work around is to use DirectorySearcher, but I don't know how to use this tool to get what I need as a tad delimited text file

Comment: Try and remove it from the get-adgroup command as well

Comment: I had already removed that, without the properties on Get-ADUser it now fails a lot quicker after only 7MB

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer this as an alternative to your script. It uses the AD SnapIn, and builds a user list as needed.

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
$Domain = 'DomainName'
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Name,GroupCategory,ManagedBy,Members | ForEach-Object {
$Users = @()
$Results = @()
ForEach($Group in $Groups){
    $Group.Members | ForEach{  
        $UserDN = $_
        If($Users.DistinguishedName -contains $UserDN){
            $User = $Users | Where{$_.DistinguishedName -eq $UserDN}
        }Else{
            $User = Get-ADUser $UserDN -Properties DisplayName,Description,DistinguishedName,MemberOf,Name,SamAccountName
            $Users += $User
        }
        $Results += [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Domain' = $Domain
            'Group Name'= $Group.Name
            'Type' = $Group.GroupCategory
            'Description' = $User.Description
            'Distinguished Name' = $User.DistinguishedName
            'Managed By' = $Group.ManagedBy
            'Members' = $User.MemberOf
            'Full Name' = $User.Name
            'User Name' = $User.SamAccountName
            'Display Name' = $User.DisplayName
        }
    }
} 
$Results | Export-Csv -delimiter "`t" -path C:\Test.txt –nti
```

Now if that gives you indexing errors, or memory issues you could collect users per group, and output each group to a CSV appending as you go. To do that you would add a new line immediately after `ForEach($Group in $Groups){` to read:

```
$GroupMembers = @()
```

Change `$Results += [PSCustomObject]@{` to be:

```
$GroupMembers += [PSCustomObject]@{
```

And finally change the last two lines to be:

```
    $GroupMembers | Export-Csv -delimiter "`t" -path C:\Test.txt –nti -append
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, but this is all it outputs

"IsReadOnly" "IsFixedSize" "IsSynchronized" "Keys" "Values" "SyncRoot" "Count"
"False" "False" "False" "System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection" "System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection" "System.Object" "10"